# How to justify and center text in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

Newbie here. I'm looking for bash script to center and justify text. My script only works with one line of text. How would you improve it?

```
#!/bin/bash
COLS=$(tput cols)
while true; do
    clear
    echo -n "Type text "
    read text
    echo
    echo "Menu"
    echo "1) Right justify  "
    echo "2) Center "
    echo "3) Exit "
    echo
    echo -n "Choose [1-3]: "
    read opt
    echo
    case $opt in
        1) printf "%*s\n" $COLS "$text"
           break
        ;;
        2) printf "%*s\n" $[$COLS/2] "$text"
           break
        ;;      
        3) break
        ;;
        *)
        echo "Error. Press [1-3]"
        break
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Answer (score 9):

As you have discovered, `$COLUMNS` is useful only in an interactive `-i` shell, so we use `columns="$(tput cols)"` instead.

The only issue I have is with the line below. It does not center text.
`printf "%*s\n" $[$COLS/2] "$text"`

Expanding on your work, here is a function to display centered text (from from a file). To call it within your script, use `display_center "file.txt"`

```
display_center(){
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#line} + columns) / 2)) "$line"
    done < "$1"
}
```

Note the use of `${#line}` (akin to `wc -m`) to count the number of characters in the line. As long as you only need to display plain text without colors/formatting, then this should work fine.

Here is a function to display right-justified text (from a file) using your same implementation of printf.

```
display_right(){
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        printf "%*s\n" $columns "$line"
    done < "$1"
}
```

You can also do similar things with tput and echo, but the example below is not so robust (i.e. will fail with long strings).

```
row=0
col=$(( ($(tput cols) - ${#text}) / 2))
tput clear
tput cup $row $col
echo "$text"
```

Also, you may want to consider using `dialog` or `select` to generate your menu. It would make your script significantly cleaner.
http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Select_loop
https://serverfault.com/questions/144939/multi-select-menu-in-bash-script

Comment: What if I also want to add colors?

Comment: This works for me better: `done <<< "$1"`

Comment: What does the `*` in `%*s` signify? It looks like it causes `printf` to accept the padding size as an argument instead of hard-coding it in the string, but I have never seen it before and I didn't find it in any manuals. _Edit_: apparently this is part of normal C `printf()` functionality, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4133356/2954547. It turned out that it _was_ in my man page for `printf(3)`, and I had just missed it.

Comment: Probably not accepted because it doesn't justify centered text. But it's a nice start and helpful nonetheless

Answer (score 5):

```c
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
{
  z = 92 - length
  y = int(z / 2)
  x = z - y
  printf "%*s%s%*s\n", x, "", $0, y, ""
}
```

Input

```
hello world
alpha bravo charlie delta
```

Output

```
                                         hello world
                                  alpha bravo charlie delta
```

Comment: `awk '{ z = '$(tput cols)' - length; y = int(z / 2); x = z - y; printf "%*s%s%*s\n", x, "", $0, y, ""; }'`

Answer (score 5):

I've been having fun with scripting for a while. I'm a carpenter and mechanic by trade so bare with me lol.  I know this is an old question but I recently was looking for something similar to fancy up an overly complicated Arch installation script I've been working on and never found an answer that fit my needs.  So I wrote a (probably hackish) function that gives a few options to simplify the formatting I was looking for.  I figured I'd share in case anyone was interested.  This is all done in zsh.

```
# Formatting using printf
# 
# _L == total length for 'L' and 'R' options
# tl == total length for 'C' option
# _c == center for 'C' option ( tl / 2 )
# fill == filler character or space by default
# 
# Default lengths declared at top of function
# 
# usage $) f_M [string] [L,R,C] [character count]
#       -S option:
#       $) f_M -S [character] [total length (- for default 'space')]
#        -3rd var ($3) is needed for filler character ($2) or
#         else ($2) is total length
# 
# 

f_M () {
    tl=72
    _c=36
    _L=16
    f_numread () {
        printf $1 | sed ':a;s/\B[0-9]\{3\}\>/,&/;ta'
    }
    f_C () {
        local x=$(printf $1 | wc -c)
        local y=$(expr $_c - $(expr $x / 2))
        local z=$(expr $tl - $y)
        local space=' '
        printf "%${y}s%-${z}s\n" "$space" "$1"
    }
    case $1 in
        -S)
            fill=' '
            if [[ -n $2 ]]; then
                if [[ -n $3 ]]; then
                    fill="$2"
                    if [[ $3 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                        tl=$3
                    fi
                else
                    if [[ $2 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                        tl=$2
                    fi
                fi
            fi
            printf "${fill}%.0s" {1..$tl}
            ;;
        *)
            if [[ $3 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                tl=$3
                _L=$3
                _c=$(expr $tl / 2)
            fi
            if [[ $1 =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
                local x=$(f_numread $1)
                case $2 in
                    L)
                        printf "%-${_L}s\n" "$x" ;;
                    R)
                        printf "%${_L}s\n" "$x" ;;
                    C)
                        f_C $x ;;
                    "")
                        printf '%s\n' $x
                esac
            else
                case $2 in
                    L)
                        printf "%-${_L}s\n" "$1" ;;
                    R)
                        printf "%${_L}s\n" "$1" ;;
                    C)
                        f_C $1 ;;
                    "")
                        printf '%s\n' $1
                esac
            fi
            ;;
    esac
}
```

Here's some examples of how I use it...

```
# Default character length is 72

[user@arch]$ printf '%s\n' "<$(f_M -S)>"
<                                                                        >

[user@arch]$ printf '%s\n' "<$(f_M -S = 50)>"
<==================================================>

# To change the 'fill' character(s), a 3rd argument is required
# So I set '-' to keep my default value
# There is probably a better way to do it but this fit my needs

[user@arch]$ printf '%s\n' "<$(f_M -S = -)>"
<========================================================================>

# Because of what I was trying to do and to get multiple uses out of
# one function, I use separate variables for 'C' than for 'L' and 'R'

[user@arch]$ printf '%s\n%s\n%s\n' "<$(f_M 'left' L 72)>" \
    "<$(f_M 'center' C)>" "<$(f_M 'right' R 72)>"
<left                                                                    >
<                                 center                                 >
<                                                                   right>

# It will also take a string that is only numbers and make
# it more "human readable"

[user@arch]$ num=12345678
[user@arch]$ printf '%s\n' "<$(f_M ${num} C 50)>"
<                    12,345,678                    >
```

And to get even more creative I can add another function that will automagically make a fancy text box using an array...

```
#!/bin/zsh

f_fancy_box () {
    local s=''
    for s in ${text[@]}; do
        case $s in
            000) printf '%b\n' "<$(f_M -S = -)>" ;;
            ---) printf '%b\n' "| $(f_M -S - 70) |" ;;
            *) printf '%b\n' "|$(f_M $s C)|" ;;
        esac
    done
}

text=(
"000"
" "
"It is hobbies like this"
"that keep me from ever"
"getting any sleep lol"
" "
"---"
" "
"But I think"
"it is worth it"
":P"
" "
"000"
)

f_fancy_box

exit
```

OUTPUT:

```
<========================================================================>
|                                                                        |
|                         It is hobbies like this                        |
|                         that keep me from ever                         |
|                          getting any sleep lol                         |
|                                                                        |
| ---------------------------------------------------------------------- |
|                                                                        |
|                               But I think                              |
|                             it is worth it                             |
|                                   :P                                   |
|                                                                        |
<========================================================================>
```

I hope somebody finds this useful!

EDIT: Changed printf '%s' in f_fancy_box to '%b'. According to the man page for printf, and to allow for character escapes, I think that's actually the appropriate command to use. Someone correct me if I'm wrong...

Answer (score 2):

#### Without destroying line contents?

This solution will put text in the center of the line in which the cursor is currently on, **without** printing spaces around its borders. Its useful if you want to center text without destroying what is currently printed on the line.

> **Notice:** Your shell must support ANSI escape sequences for his example to work.

```
#!/bin/bash
print_center(){
    local x
    local y
    text="$*"
    x=$(( ($(tput cols) - ${#text}) / 2))
    echo -ne "\E[6n";read -sdR y; y=$(echo -ne "${y#*[}" | cut -d';' -f1)
    echo -ne "\033[${y};${x}f$*"
}

# main()

# clear the screen, put the cursor at line 10, and set the text color
# to light blue.
echo -ne "\\033[2J\033[10;1f\e[94m"

# do it!
print_center 'A big blue title!'
```

The cursor will be left at the end of "title!" in this example.  Use another ANSI sequence to relocate the cursor as you see fit.

---

### Pros

- Works over SSH
- Can resize device buffer without centering issues (dynamic)
- Does not destroy line contents
- ASCII game / animation friendly.

### Cons

- Will not work if your terminal does not support ANSI escape sequences
- Not intended for rolling log output.
- Depends on bash

---

Answer (score 1):

A **function** that receives text and centers it horizontally, an **array** can also be used to enter the text.

It works as follows, a **string** is passed to the function and it is saved in an array, then with a **for loop** the array is traversed, printing each line in the center of the terminal.

```
function centerText() {
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    declare -a text=()
    text+=($*)
    for((i=0;i<${#text[@]};i++)); do
        printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#text[i]} + columns) / 2)) "${text[i]}"
    done
}
```

Here is a example:

```
function centerText() {
    columns="$(tput cols)"
    declare -a text=()
    text+=($*)
    for((i=0;i<${#text[@]};i++)); do
        printf "%*s\n" $(( (${#text[i]} + columns) / 2)) "${text[i]}"
    done
}

declare -a text=(
'First'
'Second'
'Third'
)

centerText ${text[@]}
sleep 5
```

Output:

```
                                     First
                                     Second
                                     Third
```

P.D: Sorry if there is something wrongly worded, my native language is not English.

Answer (score 0):

I was also struggling for aligning texts in my bash script so I found solution it is:

```
# echo -e "\t Hello World!"
```

Answer (score 0):

To print text at center:

```
echo "Some Text" | sed  -e :a -e "s/^.\{1,$(tput cols)\}$/ & /;ta" | tr -d '\n' | head -c $(tput cols)
```

Output:

```
                                    Some Text
```